# How can i open a new tab but be on the same page in aura component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

In an aura component , I am trying to open a new component automatically using window.open but that is taking me to the new tab instaed of being on the same page. I want to be on the same page and open a new tab.

Comment: what do you mean automatically you should probably share your code where are you putting window.open also [ask]

Comment: My component :
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
  <aura:attribute name="pageReference" type="Object"/>  
    <aura:attribute name="url" type="String"/>
    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
    
    <div>
     I am your first component !!
    </div>
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.mycomp}"/>
</aura:component>

Comment: Controller :
({
    mycomp: function(cmp, event, helper) {
      var navService = cmp.find("navService");
      var pageReference = {
       "type": "standard__component",
        "attributes": {
         "componentName": "c__PQRTEST"
         }, 
             "state": {
                             'message':'This is the target page'
                                  } };
       cmp.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);
  const handleUrl = (url) => {
      window.open(); 
         };
 navService.generateUrl(cmp.get("v.pageReference")).then(handleUrl);
      }
     })

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do this like target="_blank" or anything. But there is a hacky way to do this with a little JavaScript

this can be done by simulating ctrl + click (or any other key/event combinations that open a background tab) on a dynamically generated a element with its href attribute set to the desired url

```
function openNewBackgroundTab(){
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = "http://www.google.com/";
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    //the tenth parameter of initMouseEvent sets ctrl key
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                true, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Comment: Actually , I  need to get it opened automatically and not with any click